# How to reach parent parent text using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Using `this.parentElement.parentElement.textContent = this.textContent;` i change the parent of partent text from whatever `clicked`element is!

The block which contains that is:

```
$(".class99 li").click(function (event) {
   var text_parrent = $(this).text();//new code
   //new code
   this.parentElement.parentElement.textContent = this.textContent;
});
```

How to get the parent of the parent using jquery?

I wish to be compatible with `.empty()` and `.append()` methods!

Also, I need to change in this method because the page is more dynamically and is changed and changed multiple time!

Comment: [jQuery closest is your friend](https://api.jquery.com/closest)

Comment: The problem is: I try whith this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent jQuery code uses the `.parent()` method.

```
$(".class99 li").click(function (event) {
   var text_parrent = $(this).text();
   $(this).parent().parent().text(text_parrent);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized that some part of the code act in a weird mode!